# Android Tutorial contains a static code block, what's the reasoning for this?

Tags: java, android, static

I'm working through [this Android SQLite tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

I've got it working, but in section 9.4 we build a class that extends ContentProvider. 
If you look under where the UriMatcher is declared and instantiated you'll see a static block of code.

```
  static {
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH, TODOS);
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH + "/#", TODO_ID);
  }
```

I'm guessing this is here because the UriMatcher is declared static itself. Is that correct? 
Why can those two lines of code in the static code block not be called in the onCreate method? And finally what is the general purpose of static code blocks like this?

Here's a bigger section of the class for some context:

```
public class MyTodoContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

  // database
  private TodoDatabaseHelper database;

  // used for the UriMacher
  private static final int TODOS = 10;
  private static final int TODO_ID = 20;

  private static final String AUTHORITY = "de.vogella.android.todos.contentprovider";

  private static final String BASE_PATH = "todos";
  public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
      + "/" + BASE_PATH);

  public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE
      + "/todos";
  public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE
      + "/todo";

  private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
  static {
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH, TODOS);
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH + "/#", TODO_ID);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreate() {
    database = new TodoDatabaseHelper(getContext());
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: It's called a "static initializer". It can add extra initialization to static things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static code block executes only once when a Class is *initialized* i.e, after it is *loaded*. But

```
   static {
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH, TODOS);
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH + "/#", TODO_ID);
   }
```

won't execute whenever `onCreate()` is called because the class would have already been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are used in a static context, i.e. a static block or a static method. Instead of creating a static method which will have to be called somewhere, the authors of the tutorial created a static block which will be called when the class is initialized (instead of being called explicitly in a method).

Answer (score 0):

A static block is executed only once at the moment the class is used for the first time. You put code in the static block when it does not have to be executed for each new instance.